# How to apply tokenize to a particular column in a dataframe by using python?

Tags: python, regex, nltk, tokenize

I have a dataframe having three columns. One of the column from the dataframe need to apply tokenization. I am getting **TypeError : expected string or bytes-like object, got 'float'** .

```
import pandas as pd
import os
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\......PATH\sample_regex.xlsx")    
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
regexp = RegexpTokenizer('\w+')
df['CDnew'] = df['CD'].apply(regexp.tokenize)
```

May I request to resolve this issue, please?

Thanks in advance.

Data
[image]

I am trying to tokenize the words from third column and keep tokenize words in a new column. But I am getting *TypeError : expected string or bytes-like object, got 'float'*.

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered was due to the presence of NaN (Not a Number) values in the 'CD' column of your DataFrame.

Check whether your column have multiple data types.

```
print(df['CD'].apply(type).value_counts())
```

This will show you the count of each data type present in the 'CD' column.

You can convert all non-string values to strings using the `astype(str)` method before applying the tokenizer.

```
df['CD'] = df['CD'].astype(str)  # Convert all values to strings
regexp = RegexpTokenizer('\w+')
df['CDnew'] = df['CD'].apply(regexp.tokenize)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But this code gives warning. After trying with df.loc[:,'CD'] = df.loc[:,'CD'].astype('string') I found the dtype is object for column 'CD'

Answer (score 0):

This way it works:

```
df.loc[:,'CDnew'] = df.loc[:,'CD'].apply(regexp.tokenize)
```